# How do I take direct debit infomation on my website to be passed to direct debit provider

Tags: mysql, forms, payment-processing

Basically.
Ive got a website where members sign up and set up a direct debit for their membership.
So they can have the option of pay monthly or pay every 3 months.

We are using London and Zurich for our direct debits provider. So they handle all the mandates, payments, late, new, etc

They emailed a very lengthy documentation regarding inputs and outputs, but no where does it even begin to say where we start. It includes what information our form must receive, whether its a string or integer

example
Example XML SOAP Call for GetScheduledFuturePaymentsRequest

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
    /"xmlns:web="https://webservices.Landz.co.uk" 
    xmlns:web1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi" 
    xmlns:web2="https://webservices.landz.co.uk">
<soapenv:Header/>    
    <soapenv:Body>       <web:GetScheduledFuturePayments>          <web:request>
         <web1:Credentials>                                
    <web2:Group>4000</web2:Group>        
            <web2:SecurityCode>01234567890123456789</web2:SecurityCode>        

    </web1:Credentials>                     
    <web1:AccountRef>4000:100TEST25</web1:AccountRef>          </web:request>  
         </web:GetScheduledFuturePayments>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope
```

My friend thinks we just make a database matching their fields they have said is needed and then give them access to the database? Surely this has to be more secure than that. Were taking peoples card details, address, phone numbers, names etc

How do we collect the needed information (debit card details) via an online form and send it to them?

Does anyone know of any examples or tutorials of how this is usually done please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My friend thinks we just make a database matching their fields they have said is needed and then give them access to the database?

No, that's completely wrong. This has nothing to do with databases.

[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is a protocol for making remote procedure calls. The information you've been provided by your debit provider should have details on what server you would perform this call on, and how — contact them for details.